# regex - Searching for only character pairs

Tags: regular-expression, patterns

I have the following data from which I mean to extract only those lines which contain "bb" only. Not "b" or "bbb" or anything else just "bb".

```
abb
abbb
aabbcc
aabab
abbbbc
```

Now when I use the following combination of commands-:

```
cat file1 | grep "bb[^b]
```

I am getting the output as all the lines in my sample file-:

```
abb
abbb
aabbcc
aabab
abbbbc
```

The expected I want is -:(The lines that contain only "bb")

```
abb
aabbcc
```

What is the regular expression that can achieve this ?

**abbbabb** is not valid. I am looking for lines that contain only **bb** and no other pattern of **b**. The line will contain only two, consecutive **b** and no other b characters at all.

Comment: Is this a valid result? `abbbcbb` ??

Comment: @KasiyA No. Only lines that contain **bb**.

Comment: @KasiyA Thanks for pointing that out. I am looking for a regex that filters lines that contain only **bb** or pairs of **bb**

Comment: what exactly about pair of **bb**? Does `bbabb` is valid and `abbacbbcabb` is not valid in your case? hard to understand. Please edit your question to including all possible ways that you want to get. your input example is not clear and not enough good.

Comment: @KasiyA hmm you are right. I have edited my question. I am wanting only **bb** pattern and nothing else. No other occurrence of **b** must be there.

Comment: `abbbabb is not valid` why? it's so hard to understand your question. Could you provide some examples for valid and invalid matches?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Lines that contain the pattern **bb** and no other pattern of b. aaabb, bbccccaaaa is valid. Invalid are bbbbaa,bbaabbbcc,baac.

Comment: Then you could use this `grep '^[^b]*bb[^b]*$' file` already mentioned by PM.

Comment: I deleted my answer since the solution to your problem as stated now is actually solved by what [PM had originally posted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169524/22222).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the most straight-forward way is:

```
grep '^[^b]*bb[^b]*$' file1
```

---

Btw, for commands like `grep` that accept a file name argument it's more efficient to do

```
grep '^[^b]*bb[^b]*$' file1
```

or

```
grep '^[^b]*bb[^b]*$' < file1
```

(the latter working if no file argument is supported, too)

than

```
cat file1 | grep '^[^b]*bb[^b]*$'
```

and often more flexible.

Comment: `echo ababba | grep '^[^b]*bb[^b]*$'`

Comment: Or correct it :)

Comment: @terdon: If I understand the OP `"bbaa"` _should_ be printed.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: I'm not sure from the OP if `"ababba"` is acceptable or not. Yes, it contains `bb`, but it also contains an additional `b`. So I might wait for clarification before modifying / removing my answer.

Comment: So it should, sorry, wrong example. I was thinking of something like `echo "babb" | grep '^[^b]*bb[^b]*$'` where the string should match but the 1st letter is `b`. You rule that out with `^[^b]`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging it turns out that this was actually the correct answer. It was not answering the question as asked but PM seems to have deduced the OP's true intent. +1 for clairvoyance!

Comment: @terdon: I've found that mind-reading is a handy skill when answering questions on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
grep '\(^\|[^b]\)bb\([^b]\|$\)'
```

or

```
grep -E '(^|[^b])bb([^b]|$)'
```

That is: search for an occurrence of `bb` that is preceded by either the beginning of the line or a character different from `b`, and that is followed by either a character different from `b` or the end of the line.